# How to use p5.js sound in instance mode

Tags: javascript, audio, instance, p5.js

I'm trying to make a website with multiple p5 canvases on the same page, so after a lot of research, I came to the conclusion that the most adequate way to do that is by using instance mode on p5.
I spent the whole day trying to understand the instance mode, i even found a converter online that converts it for me, but I'm trying to do it all by my self using it just to check errors. The problem is that i can't find a way to use sound in my sketch using instance mode. the code i have is a lot more complex, but even trying just the basic it still does not work.

```js
var s = function(p) {

  let song;

  p.preload = function() {
    p.song = load('thunder.mp3')
  }

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(720, 200);
    p.background(255, 0, 0);
    p.song.loop();
  };

};

var myp5 = new p5(s, 'c1');
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    <style> body {padding: 0; 
        margin: 0;
    } 
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="c1"></div> <br>
    <div id="c2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can test it here: https://editor.p5js.org/jgsantos.dsn/sketches/rUWb6Nurt

This code works great in the global mode:

```js
let song;

function preload() {
  song = loadSound('thunder.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 200);
  background(255,0,0);
  song.loop();
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can test it here https://editor.p5js.org/jgsantos.dsn/sketches/_lQcDqOsp

It shows this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined (: line 9)"
What am I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you try to play a sound in instance mode? Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes: Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined (: line 9)

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/jgsantos.dsn/sketches/rUWb6Nurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to post the exact code you're running. Your question contains different code than the link you posted in the comments.

But taking a step back, here's how I would think about instance mode and libraries:

- Instance mode means that the variables and functions that belong to a **sketch** are now referenced via a variable, in your case the `p` variable.
- But variables and functions that belong to a **library** are still referenced directly, i.e. in "global mode".

In other words, you don't want to reference the `load()` (or is it `loadSound()`?) function using instance mode. You should still reference that function directly, since it's coming from a library instead of from a specific sketch.